# Adding an images folder to GitHub Rep

Tags: html, github

I need help with creating a dedicated folder for my images in my Website repository, and heres how it looks right now.[Image of my repository rigt now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0xd2.jpg)

**Side-Note:** I'm not using Git to push or commit these folders, all I'm doing is dumping these folders form my computers storage into github.

If the image doesn't work, heres the link to the rep.
[Link to my repository](https://github.com/Kashyap-Sukshavasi/HTML-website-practice-1)

If anybody could help me with this, that would be a lifesaver.
Thank You.

So I tried importing the images folder itslef tat is located on my computer, and that didn't work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide this answer, but I believe this is an excellent opportunity to learn some Gitfu.  As this would be so much easier if you had git tracking your repo on your local machine.

First off, I believe you are using the "Add File" functionality on GitHub to upload you files.  You can use this functionality to add folders as well.  Just provide a slash after the root folder name and then add some dummy file name.  This will create the dummy file in your new folder.

After having creating the folder you can upload the files you want into that folder using the same add file mechanism. One thing to keep in mind doing things this way you will have to manually delete the files from their previous location in GitHub.  As well as delete the dummy file you created from the step above.

Now that I've answered the question, I highly recommend you learn git.  It will save you so much time in the future.